# How to I write linear-gradient @mixin -webkit in scss compliant way

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I am trying to write a linear-gradient style, but visual studio code is giving me a warning

> Also define the standard property 'mask-image' for compatibiity

> Also define the standard property 'mask-size' for compatibiity

the website loads fine but is there a way for me to make the warnings go away?

Thanks!

```
@mixin mask-image($shine) {
-webkit-mask-image: $shine;
-webkit-mask-size: 200%;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Berkshire Swash";
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
    animation: shine 2s linear infinite;
    @include mask-image(linear-gradient(-75deg, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 30%, #000 50%, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 70%));
}

@keyframes shine {
    from { -webkit-mask-position: 150%; }
    to { -webkit-mask-position: -50%; }
  }
```

Comment: everywhere you have `-webkit-X:Y` add `X:Y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply like below:

```css
@mixin mask-image($shine) {
mask-image: $shine;
mask-size: 200%;
-webkit-mask-image: $shine;
-webkit-mask-size: 200%;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Berkshire Swash";
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
    animation: shine 2s linear infinite;
    @include mask-image(linear-gradient(-75deg, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 30%, #000 50%, rgba(0,0,0,.6) 70%));
}

@keyframes shine {
    from { -webkit-mask-position: 150%;mask-position: 150%; }
    to { -webkit-mask-position: -50%;mask-position: -50%; }
  }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. Add the extra lines 
`mask-image: $shine;`
`mask-size: 200%;`
made the warning go away.

from { -webkit-mask-position: 150%;mask-position: 150%; }
to { -webkit-mask-position: -50%;mask-position: -50%; }

made the effect stopped working.

I changed it to the following and the effect works fine
        from { -webkit-mask-position: 150%;  }
        to { -webkit-mask-position: -50%;  }
        from { mask-position: 150%; }
        to { mask-position: -50%; }

The issue is now solved. Thanks so much!